# SQL Server query / function to round up to half

Tags: sql-server, rounding

I need a function which will always round up to nearest whole or half hour in SQL Server.

Ex.

```
1.2 = 1.5
1.5 = 1.5
1.6 = 2.0
1.0 = 1.0
0.2 = 0.5
0.8 = 1.0
```

I found many options on how to solve ALMOST this - but I would like one efficient one for this purpose specific.

Thanks..

Comment: [CEILING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are dealing with numbers, the simplest way is to multiply by 2, take the Ceiling (round up to nearest whole number), then divide by 2.

```
Select Ceiling(1.2 * 2) / 2
Select Ceiling(1.6 * 2) / 2
```

Since your question mentioned "whole or half hour", here's a bit of code that accommodates DateTime data:

```
Declare @Temp Table(Data DateTime)

Insert Into @Temp Values('20131114 11:00')
Insert Into @Temp Values('20131114 11:15')
Insert Into @Temp Values('20131114 11:30')
Insert Into @Temp Values('20131114 11:45')
Insert Into @Temp Values('20131114 11:59')

Select Data, DateAdd(Minute, Ceiling(DateDiff(Minute, '0:00', Data) / 30.0) * 30, '0:00')
From   @Temp
```

Comment: Thanks.. I'm really pleased with this solution. Real simple, short and efficient :)